# why can't i get this div to go 100% height

Tags: css

I have a div that is wrapped in a few other divs that are all 100%. I have it this way because I have an outer div with a slight border image that I want wrapped around the entire page.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container" >
    <div style="padding-top:15px; height:100%;">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="contentContainer">
            test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body { margin: 0 auto; color: #333333;  }
html, body {  color: #000000;  margin:0;  padding:0;  height:100%; }

.wrapper {width:940px; margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; background:#fff; overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto; height:100%;}

.container {min-height:100%;  height: auto !important; height:100%;  margin: 0 auto -30px;  width:980px; background:URL(images/bg_sides.jpg) repeat-y #f4f4f4;}

.contentContainer {width:920px; margin:0 auto; height:100%; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hc3Xu/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `height: auto !important` rule in .container is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. that works. I forgot it was necessary for my footer to stay at the bottom. at least I can probably rearrange things now that I know though.

Comment: @Sackling, while you're free to accept any answer you wish, in all fairness, welldan97 posted it first and really deserves the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks, @Sparky672. Also I've got a link to demo in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/c3Lxg/

I've removed `height: auto !important` from `.container` which overrided other heights.

Answer (score 0):

`.container` has `height: auto !important` and `height: 100%`.  The `!important` rule is overriding.  Remove it and you're fine.